# How do you do padding for bootstrap img-fluid

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Not much of a front end developer, I tried all kinds of trix, `margin`, `p-0`, `style="padding:20px"` but nothing seems to be moving my fluid image to position it where I want during page load, assistance much appreciated.

```
**HTML**  
<img class="img-fluid" src="~/Content/MyImage.jpg"/>
    

**CSS**
.img-fluid {
  padding-left:20px;
}
```

Comment: How do you want to position your image?

Comment: Maybe you could give a full demo using Codepen or JSFiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what you exactly want.

So I have guesswork you want use "Bootstrap" because you did written "img-fluid" class.

I think the code below will help you.

**HTML Code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <!-- Bootstrap CSS CDN -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <!-- Bootstrap JS CDN -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <title>Demo</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="root" class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <img class="img-fluid" src="https://placehold.it/1920x1080.png" alt="image"/>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS Code**

```
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.row > div {
  padding-left: 0px;
  padding-right: 0px;
}

.img-fluid {
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
}
```